# View the assembly code for C source code through gcc in the terminal

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly

I run **gcc -S filename.c** or **gcc filename.c -s** successfully but no output. So how do you view the assembly code itself?

Comment: It compiles into `filename.s`.  View it with `less`.  Or use `-o -` to set the output file to `-` (which means stdout).

Comment: The lower-case `-s` used to be for stripping executables when linking; are you sure that does anything with assembler?  Upper-case `-S` is for 'generate assembly'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: both those commands are valid.  `gcc -S foo.c` compiles to `foo.s`.  `gcc -s foo.c` compiles and links to a stripped binary called `a.out`.  You're correct that using both together is useless (`gcc -S -s foo.c`), but that's not what the OP said they did.

Comment: @PeterCordes — the main point of my comment is that it is pointless to look for assembler files after running `gcc filename.c -s` — there won't be any generated and kept.  Thanks for confirming that `-s` is nominally for 'stripping the executable'.  On my Macs, it (`-s`) is a no-op, or generates a warning from `ld` — `ld: warning: option -s is obsolete and being ignored`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: oh, yeah I see what you mean.  I assume the OP didn't run `ls -lrt` to see recently-modified files in the directory, and was expecting output to the terminal directly, not a file.  That's why I commented about using  `gcc foo.c -O1 -S -fverbose-asm -masm=intel -o - | less`.  But yes, `-s` is an option you definitely don't want to use if you're going to disassemble an executable with `objdump -drwC -Mintel a.out | less`

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't use them together but different times to check both. I'm sure only about gcc -S foo.c  which now worked. I have seen the .s file

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was wrong to use -s. That compiles to a.out. Agreed! Thanks.